# AWS CLI Lambda Single Invoke Causes Multiple Invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a long running lambda (15 minutes).

I call it with this:

```
aws lambda invoke --region us-west-2 --profile prof --function-name func --invocation-type Event response.json
```

I expect the lambda to be invoked once. However, its usually invoked at least 3 times.

[image]

I can try to avert this by setting `reservedConcurrency=1`, but I at times get:

```
TooManyRequestsException: Rate Exceeded.
```

Why was my lambda called 3 times? Is there something in the documentation that could help demystify this behaivor?

MY THEORY:

My theory is that because it's a long running lambda, the lambda will be called a few times because the timeout on some client is not long enough.

Is it because I have retry attempts at 2 in the settings?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch Logs to look for error messages from the function? Make sure you can see some output in the logs (eg debug messages) to be sure that logging is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something in the documentation that could help demystify this behaivor?

I seems there are some errors in your lambda function causing it to fail.
If this happens during **asynchronous** invocation,
the lambda is going to retry your
function [twice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html):

> **Lambda retries function errors twice**. If the function doesn't have
> enough capacity to handle all incoming requests, events might wait
> in the queue for hours or days to be sent to the function. You can
> configure a **dead-letter queue** on the function to capture events
> that weren't successfully processed.

This would explain why your function is invoked **3 times**: 1 normal time + 2 retries.

Usually `CloudWatch Logs` would enable you to identify the issue. [Dead Letter Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) is also helpful to capture the events which lead to failures.